# NSScrollview scrollPoint doesnt scroll to point

Tags: cocoa, scroll, nsscrollview

I'm trying for 2 hours now to get my scrollview to scroll a specific point. Its frustrating and I cant tell you why it wont work.

I have a scrollview and in it is a NSClipView. 
They are getting created in my AppDelegate right before my scrollPoint.

but either

```
[myclipview scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(1000.0, 0.0)];
```

works, neither

```
[[self.scrollView documentView] scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(1000.0, 0.0)];
```

(I want it to scroll all the way to the right,but not with any flip method or sth.)

Found this question
[Why is [[NSScrollView documentView] scrollPoint:] not working in loadView method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326617/why-is-nsscrollview-documentview-scrollpoint-not-working-in-loadview-method)

And did not help me, I dont try it in the loadView method either. scrollView and myclipview arent nil either. Any tips for me? The scrollview works fine except it wont scroll to my position.

**EDIT**

just to be shure, i made this small test project:

```
NSScrollView* myscrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)];
NSClipView* myclipview = [[NSClipView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 400)];
[myscrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[myscrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
[myscrollview setDocumentView:myclipview];

[[myscrollview documentView] scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(400, 300)];

[self.window.contentView addSubview:myscrollview];
```

and it doesnt scroll anywhere, i think i'm missing something here...?

Comment: just to be shure i made this small testproject:

Comment: I think you need to set the frame for the documentView of NSScrollView instance especially the height.

Comment: @PatrickTescher There is no "setContentOffset" outside of iOS. The question is about "NSScrollView" not "UIScrollView"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Small Test Project what you have needs to be changed in the following way.
I have tried this and seems to be working. Do let me know if you still have any more issues.

Hope this will fix the issue : )

```
   NSScrollView* myscrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10.0f, 100.0f, 200, 200)];
    NSClipView* myclipview = [[NSClipView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10.0f, 100.0f, 500, 400)];
    [myscrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [myscrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
    [myscrollview setDocumentView:myclipview];

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:myscrollview];


    //******** Code Changes from here**********
    //This Calculation needs to be done 
    CGPoint newScrollOrigin=NSMakePoint(0.0,NSMaxY([[myscrollview documentView] frame])
                                -NSHeight([[myscrollview contentView] bounds]));

    //Increment/Decrement in x of newScrollOrigin will move the scroll position horizontally
    //Increment/Decrement in y of newScrollOrigin will move the scroll position vertically.

    //Incrementation of Values depends on your requirement.
    CGPoint setOrigin = CGPointMake(newScrollOrigin.x , newScrollOrigin.y - 120.0f);

    //Set the Scroll Point
    [[myscrollview contentView] scrollToPoint:setOrigin];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!
But I already tried scrollToPoint, and it does a different thing. It starts the scrollview at that location. But I cant scroll to the area which is "left" from the Point. I want to "put the scrollbar" to another point, and not the bounds of the scrollview. The function I need should be scrollPoint, but I have no Idea why it doesnt do a thing.

Comment: //Incrementation of Values depends on your requirement.Increment of x will move the scroller to right and decrement of x will move the scroller to left.
    CGPoint setOrigin = CGPointMake(newScrollOrigin.x + 400.0f , newScrollOrigin.y - 120.0f);
    
    //Set the Scroll Point
    [[myscrollview contentView] scrollPoint:setOrigin];